How to use RStudio in fully updated Ubuntu 24.04?
The upgrade from Ubuntu 24.04 to 24.04.1 broke my RStudio install (altogether, 11 packages were broken by the upgrade). I removed RStudio and also upgraded it to the latest version (2024.04.2-764-amd64.deb), but the error persists. By itself, R (v4.3.3) runs smoothly.
This is the error I get. I do not even know what it refers to - and hence, where to start looking:
laptop@user:~$ rstudio 
[48623:0903/170856.125096:FATAL:credentials.cc(127)] Check failed: . : Permission denied (13)
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)


Have run into this same bug. Not keen on disabling the newer security features so my current solution is running 22.04 in a VM and using that for any apps that aren't yet ready for 24.04. Hopefully this will only be a temporary solution for a couple of weeks/months and the apps that aren't yet updated to work with 24.04 get updated soon.

The bug has been reported, and has been resolved in the development branch of RStudio.
The next version of RStudio cranberry-hibiscus will not have this bug. While it is not released yet, you can download it from here.
Here is how to install .deb packages in Ubuntu 24.04.

In addition to that, you may have to permanently disable Ubuntu's apparmor namespace restrictions for RStudio to launch.
Enter the following command, and reboot.
echo 'kernel.apparmor_restrict_unprivileged_userns = 0' | 
  sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/20-apparmor-donotrestrict.conf


I can not yet upvote, so thanks Archisman!

Ha, and after following the apparmor posts I ended with the Balena Etcher question, another thing that did not work after the upgrade. So, thanks again Archisman!

@digisus If something else is not working, please feel free to ask a new question

+1 TY. There's a newer dev version of cranberry-hibiscus from two days ago. I look forward to the RStudio team finalizing this release!
